# Jquery 1.9 - define global variable inside function on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
video.on('change', function(e){
  var $this = $(this),
  odgovor = $this.val()
  roditelj = $this.parent(),
  textarea = '<textarea class="text" id="video_opis" name=video_opis></textarea>';

 if( roditelj.find('textarea') )  window.video_opis = roditelj.find('textarea').val();
 if( video_opis && video_opis.trim() != '' ) roditelj.find('textarea').val(video_opis);

  odgovor == 'Ne' ? roditelj.append(textarea) : roditelj.find('#markItUpVideo_opis ').remove();
  roditelj.find('textarea').markItUp(mySettings);
  return false;
});
```

At the moment, after removing **textarea** (choose value isn't **Ne**), **video_opis** becomes unidentified. How can I maintain value of that variable and insert it when **textarea** is being created?

Comment: Using 'window' variables is not recommended. Try to make your own namespace in 'window' and save your value there.  Can you give an example in jsFiddle?

Comment: You want to create a global variable, inside the `change()` event-handler if doesn't already exist?

Comment: @DavidThomas When user click on radio button, and value is **Ne**, textarea is created. I want to make some kind of fail safety - if user by mistake click on wrong radio button, the value of textarea need to be brought back when user click again on radio button with value **Ne**.

Comment: So why delete/remove it at all? Simply hide it and set the 'disabled' property. That way if it remains `disabled` it shouldn't be considered 'successful' and therefore won't be submitted, if it's enabled (or simply not-`disabled`) then it *will* be submitted with the `form` (assuming you're working with a `form` here, obviously).

Comment: @DavidThomas I forgot that I can do that :D. Thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: I have a slight idea of where your problem might be, but a [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/) would really help. It's hard to know your exact expected outcome, even from your description.